# Restrict values in HTML input field at time of input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this hypothetical page I have these inputs:

```
<input type="number" min=1 max=9 required />
<input type="number" min=1 max=9 required />
<input type="number" min=1 max=9 required />
<input type="number" min=1 max=9 required />
```

The that's confusing me is I know that they're restricted if I put the inputs in a form and submit the form.

But if you go to the fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uatxcvzp/)

You can easily type in 100 or -20 or anything out side of the range of 1-9.

**Is there a way to restrict the values in an input field at the time of inputting them? / without submitting it**

(side questions: when do the min/max attributes of the input fields take effect? is it only at the time of submitting the form? Is it possible to validate the values without submitting a form?)

Comment: I think html 5 validation run when you submit form. You can use jquery validation plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) instead of html 5 validation.

Comment: In browsers that support the number field, you should get an error when you blur/leave the field. (what browser are you using?)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like **Google Chrome** will enforce the min/max values when you use a submit button on the form.

I've updated your sample, with 3 submit buttons (labelled accordingly)... one will enforce the validation, the others will show the errors, but submit anyway.

http://jsfiddle.net/uatxcvzp/12/

```
 <form>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="9" required />
    <input type="number" min="1" max="9" required />
    <input type="number" min="1" max="9" required />
    <input type="number" min="1" max="9" required />
    <br/>
    <br/><input type="button" value="Submit With No Forced Validation" onclick="this.form.submit();"/>
    <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit With No Forced Validation" onclick="this.form.submit();"/>
    <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit With Forced Validation"/>
</form>
```

In **Firefox**, the validation occurs on field blur, highlighting the field border in red and showing a tooltip explaining the error on hover.  Using either submit style will halt and require that the errors are fixed.

In **IE10**, only the native submit button will force validation when you try to submit the form.

In **Safari** on iOS9.1, it looks like it is completely ignored regardless of the submit button/code style used. :-(

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
$("input[type='number']").change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var val = $this.val();
  var span = $(".error");
  if (val > 9 || val < 1) {
    
    span.text("value must be between 1 and 9");
  }else{
   span.text("");
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.error {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min=1 max=9 required />
<input type="number" min=1 max=9 required />
<input type="number" min=1 max=9 required />
<input type="number" min=1 max=9 required />
<span class="error"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code:

```
<input type="number" min=1 max=9 required onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==1) return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

thy this its work for me

```
<input type="text" name="number" minlength='1' maxlength="9" required>
```

Comment: I just tested it out and it doesn't do anything differently

Comment: there is typo `minlenght` should be `minlength`

Comment: @jay `minlenght` (is both spelled wrong and not a valid attribute for the number field) http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html `maxlength` really only applies to test fields to limit the character length.

Comment: @karan is ri8 not `minlenght` its `minlength `

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not natively possible as an uncontrolled component and it needs to become a controlled component - either writing javascript/jQuery manually, or using a library.

If using React, you can use something like `react-hook-form` and the code would look something like below. Specifically, see the `age` input.

Full documentation is here: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      age: '',
    }
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(console.log)}>
      <input {...register("firstName", { required: true })} placeholder="First name" />
      <input {...register("lastName", { minLength: 2 })} placeholder="Last name" />

      <input
        {...register("age", {
          validate: {
            positive: v => parseInt(v) > 0,
            lessThan200: v => parseInt(v) < 200,
          }
        })}
      />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```